# How to add script for checkout item default file?

Tags: magento2, javascript, php-7, knockout

how can I add script for `Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html` file? I have to add `data-bind="click: {}"` to the product, but I don't know where I should place my function? I tried in minicart.js but it doesn't work.

Example.

```
<!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
    <div data-bind="attr: {title: product_name}, event: { click: function() { customFunc() } }" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I need to pass product data as a function parameter from this file, so it can't be global script.

SOLVED: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/355474/103513

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I was able to do it this way.

So, you had to create a file (mixin) `Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart-item-renderer-mixin` and in it add these functions.

```js
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart-item-renderer': {
                'Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart-item-renderer-mixin': true
            },
        }
    },
};
```

js

```js
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent'
], function ($, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({ 
            // code here
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this might not be the optimal solution but here is a way

Extending the default template

`app/design/frontend/VENDOR_THEME/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

You can specify your own custom css and js, they will be available for all website pages.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>

        <link src="js/custom.js"/>

    </head>
</page>
```

Then your custom.js goes there

`app/design/frontend/VENDOR_THEME/default/web/js/custom.js`

Comment: Ok, thanks. But as I understand it I will be able to embed regular javascript in this file, retrieving the element using `document.querySelector` rather than using knockout `data-bind`?

oh ok, it'll be a global script. I understand

Comment: I can't use it. I need to pass product data as a function parameter from this file.

Comment: @mrcl Sadly my understanding of knockoutJS et data binding don't go that far so I won't be able to tell you more. May be already start by checking the product_has_url valye to be sure your div is actually embeded in the html code. Searching `Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html` string in your code should allow you to find the js component used.